# Is a subspace connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$A= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : |y|>|x| \}\ \cup \ \{ (0,0)\}$

$B= \{(x, \frac{1}{x^{2}} ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x>0 \} \ \cup \ (\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$

Is it A or B connected? Why? I guess that both are connected because the sets aren't closed. We can't divided the set into 2 nonempty subsets which union give us a space. But what is a formal proof?

Comment: Make a drawing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should draw pictures for both sets.

As for $A$, you could try proving that it's connected showing that, in fact, it's more than that: it's *path-connected*. That is: every two points in $A$ can be joined with a continuous path lying inside $A$. If you can "see" which path I'm talking about, you can easily write down its formula and check it's always inside $A$. Te only difficult point is trying to joint points with $y>0$ and $y<0$.

As for the $B$: it's NOT connected. It has two clear connected components, hasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

"Not being closed" has nothing to do with connectedness.
The set $A$ is in fact *pathwise* connected: If $(x,y)\in A$ then $[0,1]\to A$, $t\mapsto(tx,ty)$ is a path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$.

For $B$ observe that the sets defined by $2x^2y>1$ and $2x^2y<1$ are open.

Comment: Why 2x2y>1 and 2x2y<1 ?
It can't be the function $y(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is is path-connected! Show that each point in $A$ can be path-connected to the origin, so the path-connected component of the origin is the whole set. Path-connectedness is strictly stronger than connectedness.

$B$ is of course disconnected. It's the union of three disjoint closed sets, topologically it's like three lines. To show it's not connected, draw its components as functions, and find out a description for the separating neighborhoods.

See [graph of the B set at WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%20y%5E2x%5E2=y%20,%20x=%20-3%20to%203,%20y%20=%20-3%20to%203) for the graph.

(edited: I misread the description of $A$)

Comment: whops, I missed the absolute values...

Comment: In B it isn't a function $y(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ ? + Rx{0}

Comment: It's a function defined implicitly: $y(x^2y-1)=0$

Comment: Why? I don't see it.

Comment: The null set of that function is the set of points of $ℝ^2$ where either of those factors is zero. So $ℝ\times {0}$ is the locus of $y=0$, and the other set is the locus of solutions of $x^2y=1$.